# SELECT query returns 1 row when there is more than 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project for my university homework. Everything works right now except for my activity list. Issue is that whenever I try to view my activity list, it only returns 1 activity instead of all the activities that are still ongoing, when I manually run the query from `phpMyAdmin`, it returns all the queries but PHP doesn't seem to get it right and I have no idea why.

I have already tried running the query from `phpMyAdmin` and simplifying my query, also added a bunch of debugging code to see where I am going wrong but all the values are correct, the query is correct and `phpMyAdmin` runs the query just fine.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM activities"; /*LIMIT " . $limit . ", " . $maxActivity;*/
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
          echo $query;
          if(!$result) {
            echo "<p class='text-danger'>There are no activities to display.</p>";
          } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $activity_id = $row['id'];
                $activity_name = $row['name'];
                $activity_description = $row['description'];
                $activity_end_date = $row['endDate'];
                $activity_start_date = $row['startDate'];
                $activity_type = $row['type'];
                $activityAuthor = $row['author'];
                $activityPublished = $row['publishedAt'];
                $activityLikes = $row['likes'];
                $activityDislikes = $row['dislikes'];
                $activityComments = $row['comments'];
                $activityViews = $row['views'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$activityAuthor'";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                if(!$result) {
                  die("MySQL Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($link));
                }
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $authorID = $row['id'];
        ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src="img/<?php echo "$activity_type";?>.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><?php echo $activity_name;?></h3>
        <p class="lead text-secondary">Proposed by <a class="text-secondary lead" href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $authorID;?>"><?php echo $activityAuthor;?></a> at <?php echo $activityPublished;?></p>

        <p><?php echo $activity_description;?></p>
        <p><strong>Starts at:</strong> <?php echo $activity_start_date;?></p>
        <p><strong>Ends at:</strong> <?php echo $activity_end_date;?></p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="config/like.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>&post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> <?php echo $activityLikes;?></a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="config/dislike.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>&post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>  <?php echo $activityDislikes;?></a>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="far fa-comment-dots"></i> <?php echo $activityComments;?></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> <?php echo $activityViews;?></button>
        <div class="mt-3"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="activity.php?post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>&page=<?php echo $page;?>&commentpage=1">View Activity</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <?php }
    }?>
```

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_array instead mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array didn't work

Comment: Does your university give minus points for unsafe code as SQL injections seams to be possible within this code?

Comment: I will take care of security later, I am aware this code can be SQL injected but it's safe for now as it's in localhost. My first priority is to have something that is stable, and in working condition. I'll take care of SQL injections once I am done with the existing bugs.

Comment: "i will take care of security later" - is something people say who definitely *don't* take care of security later. do it the right way *now*, or don't do it at all. plus: using parameterised queries will probably solve your problem automatically.

Comment: famous last words. Anyway, if you want to store multiple values, you can use `$activity_id[]`

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but at the same time I won't really lose any points for unsafe code but I'll lose a lot of points because of this awkward bug, that's why my priority lays within the existing bugs, especially this one. Will try the recommendations above, thanks.

Comment: Yep! That was silly of me to do but I didn't even realize up until now, thanks sticky bit! It works, and thanks to everyone that responded, I will take care of security now.

Comment: You overwrite `$result` with your other query. That other query isn't necessary. Use a join in the first one to get the data into its result too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM activities"; 
              $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

              if(!$result) {
                echo "<p class='text-danger'>There are no activities to display.</p>";
              } else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $activity_id = $row['id'];
                    $activity_name = $row['name'];
                    $activity_description = $row['description'];
                    $activity_end_date = $row['endDate'];
                    $activity_start_date = $row['startDate'];
                    $activity_type = $row['type'];
                    $activityAuthor = $row['author'];
                    $activityPublished = $row['publishedAt'];
                    $activityLikes = $row['likes'];
                    $activityDislikes = $row['dislikes'];
                    $activityComments = $row['comments'];
                    $activityViews = $row['views'];

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$activityAuthor'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    if(!$result) {
                      die("MySQL Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($link));
                    }
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $authorID = $row['id'];
     }

     $output.="<div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <a href='#'>
              <img class='img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0' src='img/<?php echo '$activity_type';?>.jpeg' alt=''>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <h3><?php echo $activity_name;?></h3>
            <p class='lead text-secondary'>Proposed by <a class='text-secondary lead' href='profile.php?id=<?php echo $authorID;?>'><?php echo $activityAuthor;?></a> at <?php echo $activityPublished;?></p>

            <p><?php echo $activity_description;?></p>
            <p><strong>Starts at:</strong> <?php echo $activity_start_date;?></p>
            <p><strong>Ends at:</strong> <?php echo $activity_end_date;?></p>
            <a class='btn btn-outline-success' href='config/like.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>&post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>'><i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i> <?php echo $activityLikes;?></a>
            <a class='btn btn-outline-danger' href='config/dislike.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>&post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>'><i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i>  <?php echo $activityDislikes;?></a>
            <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary'><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i> <?php echo $activityComments;?></button>
            <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary'><i class='far fa-eye'></i> <?php echo $activityViews;?></button>
            <div class='mt-3'><a class='btn btn-primary' href='activity.php?post=<?php echo $activity_id;?>&page=<?php echo $page;?>&commentpage=1'>View Activity</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>";

        }
        ?>


<?php echo $output; ?>
```